# OpenCV 4 TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'labels'

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, opencv, facial-identification

I am writing a facial recognition program and I keep getting this error when I try to train my recognizer

```
TypeError: Expected cv::UMat for argument 'labels'
```

my code is

```
def detect_face(img):
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + "haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml")
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.2, minNeighbors=5);
    if (len(faces)==0):
        return None, None
    (x, y, w, h) = faces[0]
    return gray[y:y+w, x:x+h], faces[0]

def prepare_training_data():
    faces = []
    labels = []
    for img in photo_name_list: #a collection of file locations as strings
        image = cv2.imread(img)
        face, rect = detect_face(image)
        if face is not None:
            faces.append(face)
            labels.append("me")
    return faces, labels

def test_photos():
    face_recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
    faces, labels = prepare_training_data()
    face_recognizer.train(faces, np.ndarray(labels))
```

labels is list of labels for each photo in the image list returned from prepare_training_data, and I convert it to a numpy array because I read that is what train() needs it to be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solution - labels should be list of integers, and you should use `numpy.array(labels)` (or `np.array(labels)`).

Dummy example to check an error absence:

```
labels=[0]*len(faces)
face_recognizer.train(faces, np.array(labels))
```

I haven't found any documentation for openCV face recognizers on python, so I've started to look over c++ documentation and examples. And due to [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/facerec_api.html#facerecognizer-train) this library uses `labels` input for `train` as a `std::vector<int>`. A [cpp example](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.0/da/d60/tutorial_face_main.html), provided by openCV docs, also uses `vector<int> labels`. And so on, library even have an [error for not an integer input](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/blob/ab2e83248fa1783d7c2055ef280d403ffcf968c8/modules/face/src/eigen_faces.cpp#L64).

Comment: yes, passing numeric values solves the issue. I think if includes characters in the labels, then it require encoding the label first